# Query matching() causing duplicate rows and distinct() not working

Tags: mysql, cakephp, group-by, distinct, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to filter one table Payments by a field on the associated table Invoices.

Using the function `matching()` on the query object filters correctly but causes duplicate rows. It seemed like the solution was using `distinct()`, but calling `distinct(Payments.id)` results in an invalid query. I'm doing the following in a controller action.

```php
$conditions = [
    'Payments.is_deleted =' => false
];
$args = [
    'conditions' => $conditions,
    'contain' => ['Invoices', 'Invoices.Clients'],
];
$payments = $this->Payments->find('all', $args);
if($issuer) {
    // This causes duplicate rows
    $payments->matching('Invoices', function ($q) use ($issuer) {
        return $q->where(['Invoices.issuer_id' => $issuer['id']]);
    });
    // $payments->distinct('Payments.id'); // Causes a mysql error
}
```

Am I correct in thinking that `distinct()` is what I need, and if so any idea what's missing to make it work?

I'm getting the following mysql error when uncommenting the line above:

> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #8 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'InvoicesPayments.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Full query:

```sql
SELECT
    PAYMENTS.ID AS `PAYMENTS__ID`,
    PAYMENTS.CREATED AS `PAYMENTS__CREATED`,
    PAYMENTS.MODIFIED AS `PAYMENTS__MODIFIED`,
    PAYMENTS.DATE_REGISTERED AS `PAYMENTS__DATE_REGISTERED`,
    PAYMENTS.USER_ID AS `PAYMENTS__USER_ID`,
    PAYMENTS.AMOUNT AS `PAYMENTS__AMOUNT`,
    PAYMENTS.IS_DELETED AS `PAYMENTS__IS_DELETED`,
    INVOICESPAYMENTS.ID AS `INVOICESPAYMENTS__ID`,
    INVOICESPAYMENTS.INVOICE_ID AS `INVOICESPAYMENTS__INVOICE_ID`,
    INVOICESPAYMENTS.PAYMENT_ID AS `INVOICESPAYMENTS__PAYMENT_ID`,
    INVOICESPAYMENTS.PART_AMOUNT AS `INVOICESPAYMENTS__PART_AMOUNT`,
    INVOICES.ID AS `INVOICES__ID`,
    INVOICES.CREATED AS `INVOICES__CREATED`,
    INVOICES.MODIFIED AS `INVOICES__MODIFIED`,
    INVOICES.IS_PAID AS `INVOICES__IS_PAID`,
    INVOICES.IS_DELETED AS `INVOICES__IS_DELETED`,
    INVOICES.CLIENT_ID AS `INVOICES__CLIENT_ID`,
    INVOICES.ISSUER_ID AS `INVOICES__ISSUER_ID`,
    INVOICES.NUMBER AS `INVOICES__NUMBER`,
    INVOICES.SUBTOTAL AS `INVOICES__SUBTOTAL`,
    INVOICES.TOTAL AS `INVOICES__TOTAL`,
    INVOICES.DATE_REGISTERED AS `INVOICES__DATE_REGISTERED`,
    INVOICES.CURRENCY AS `INVOICES__CURRENCY`,
    INVOICES.RECEIVER_NAME AS `INVOICES__RECEIVER_NAME`,
    INVOICES.RECEIVER_RFC AS `INVOICES__RECEIVER_RFC`,
    INVOICES.EMAIL_SENDER AS `INVOICES__EMAIL_SENDER`,
    INVOICES.PDF_PATH AS `INVOICES__PDF_PATH` 
FROM
    PAYMENTS PAYMENTS 
    INNER JOIN
        INVOICES_PAYMENTS INVOICESPAYMENTS 
        ON PAYMENTS.ID = (
            INVOICESPAYMENTS.PAYMENT_ID
        )
    INNER JOIN
        INVOICES INVOICES 
        ON (
            INVOICES.ISSUER_ID = :C0 
            AND INVOICES.ID = (
                INVOICESPAYMENTS.INVOICE_ID
            )
        ) 
WHERE
    (
        PAYMENTS.IS_DELETED = :C1 
        AND PAYMENTS.DATE_REGISTERED >= :C2 
        AND PAYMENTS.DATE_REGISTERED <= :C3
    )
GROUP BY
    PAYMENT_ID 
ORDER BY
    PAYMENTS.DATE_REGISTERED ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That behavior is expected, as matching will use an `INNER` join, and yes, grouping is how you avoid duplicates:

> As this function will create an INNER JOIN, you might want to consider calling distinct on the find query as you might get duplicate rows if your conditions don’t exclude them already. This might be the case, for example, when the same users comments more than once on a single article.

**[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Loading Associations > Filtering by Associated Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/query-builder.html#filtering-by-associated-data)**

As the error message states, your MySQL server is configured to use the strict [**`only_full_group_by` mode**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html), where your query is invalid. You can either disable that strict mode [**as mentioned by Akash prajapati**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61929854/1392379) (which can come with its own problems, as MySQL is then allowed to pretty much pick values of a group at random), or you could change how you query things in order to conform to the strict mode.

In your case where you need to group on the primary key, you could simply switch to using `innerJoinWith()` instead, unlike `matching()` this will not add any fields of that association to the `SELECT` list, and things should be fine in strict mode, as everything else is functionally dependent:

In cases where you would group on a key that would break functional dependency detection, one way to solve that could for example be to use a subquery for filtering, one that only selects that key, something along the lines of this:

```php
$conditions = [
    'Payments.is_deleted =' => false
];

$payments = $this->Payments
    ->find()
    ->contain(['Invoices.Clients']);

if($issuer) {
    $matcherQuery = $this->Payments
        ->find()
        ->select(['Payments.some_other_field'])
        ->where($conditions)
        ->matching('Invoices', function ($q) use ($issuer) {
            return $q->where(['Invoices.issuer_id' => $issuer['id']]);
        })
        ->distinct('Payments.some_other_field');

    $payments->where([
        'Payments.some_other_field IN' => $matcherQuery
    ]);
} else {
    $payments->where($conditions);
}
```

This will result in a query similar to this, where the outer query can then select all the fields you want:

```sql
SELECT
    ...
FROM
    payments
WHERE
    payments.some_other_field IN (
        SELECT
            payments.some_other_field
        FROM
            payments
        INNER JOIN
            invoices_payments ON
                payments.id = invoices_payments.payment_id
        INNER JOIN
            invoices ON
                invoices.issuer_id = ...
                AND
                invoices.id = invoices_payments.invoice_id
        WHERE
            payments.is_deleted = ...
        GROUP BY
            payments.some_other_field
    )
```

Comment: excellent – it was indeed restructuring the query that I couldn't quite get my head around, and your example helped a lot. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with sql_mode value in mysql so you need to set the sql_mode value as blank and then you can try and working fine for you.

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

Please let me know still anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but was too afraid to set the sql_mode as mentioned by @Akash and also too much in a hurry to restructure the query. So I decided to use the inherited Collection method indexBy()

[https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake\Collection\Collection::indexBy](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake%5CCollection%5CCollection::indexBy)

`$resultSetFromYourPaymentsQuery = $resultSetFromYourPaymentsQuery->indexBy('id');`

It worked like a charm and it is DB independent.

EDIT: After some more tinkering, this might not be practical for all use cases. Replacing `matching` with `innerJoinWith` as proposed in the accepted answer will probably solve it in more generalized manner.